# Is there a system primary key associated with each row?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2000

Does a system primary key or unique identifier for each row in a table exist? Like `@@ROWID`, `@@IDENTIFER`, or some other identifier that uniquely identifies each row regardless of how it was created? Using SQL Server 2000 through SQL Server 2012.

Comment: No, at least nothing you can get your hands on easily. Every row has some system-level location information - file id, page id and offset inside the page - but that information is very much internal to SQL Server and not easily accessible from the outside (and definitely not useable to select your row from T-SQL!)

Comment: Do you mean like `ROWID` in Oracle? No.

Answer (score 4):

In practical terms from a code or user perspective, no.

There is one internally (`rid`) but it is not exposed in any documented system view or function